# How to import Beta components in Shopify Polaris

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, polaris

I have not been able to access the new Text component offered by the Shopify Polaris library. I am getting the following import error:

```
The requested module '/node_modules/.vite/deps/@shopify_polaris.js?v=e5492b37' does not provide an export named 'Text'
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this? The other text components are all deprecated and I'm using the latest version of Polaris.

Comment: shopify polaris [definitely does export Text component](https://github.com/Shopify/polaris/blob/6cd75fd9a089791a79fe8aa7e43f6b54add47a45/polaris-react/src/index.ts#L366). Can you share more details?

Comment: @TwistedOwl I see the source code in my node modules and you are right but the error persists. I am using polaris version 10.15.0 and am running the shopify app using npm run dev

Comment: usually that problem occurs because the import statement is used wrong but it's hard to tell without knowing the source code. That's why I asked for more details :)

Comment: And the contents of your package.json can make a difference as well.

Comment: @TwistedOwl here is my package.json and import: https://justpaste.it/cw6s9

Comment: Weird it looks good. I have tried the same config and template, and everything works just fine. Can you share vite.config.js?

Comment: @TwistedOwl here is my vite.config.js https://justpaste.it/cgayj

Comment: I think you can try looking into: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73125972/the-requested-module-node-modules-vite-deps-vue-js-does-not-provide-an-expor

Have you checked the `/node_modules/.vite/deps/@shopify_polaris.js?v=e5492b37` file? There must be a reason why it can't find it. Sorry for the chaotic troubleshooting but I am trying to understand it as well. I've tried to reproduce but everything works on my end (except I do not use TS and from the config I can assume that you do)

Comment: restarting the development server did it for me... :)

Answer (score 0):

Manually updating version in `web/frontend/package.json` worked for me.
It was 9.24.0 by default. Changed it to 10.32.0 and restarted the development server.